# How to Create movie schedule by custom post type query

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, query-posts, scheduled-posts

I want to create movie scheduler  by custom post type query. That will display like:

"Day 1, 15 oct 2016"
1.Movie list goes here
2.Movie list goes here

"Day 2, 17 oct 2016"
1.Movie list goes here
2.Movie list goes here
3.Movie list goes here

also after the expiry of the schedule time the post will be redirect to a specific page location. I am using "Advanced custom fields" plugins.
Is there anybody can Help Me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's very good that you are using Advanced Custom Fields.
Use this for assigning running dates to movie and by making use of WP_Query you can call movies wherever is matching date.

For fetching posts you can use following code:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'  => 'movie',
   'meta_key'   => 'date',
   'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key'     => 'date',
           'value'   => array('2016-10-08'),
           'compare' => '=',
         ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```